# How can I build PHP5 Dependencies while having MariaDB installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, php, mariadb

I am trying to build php5 dependencies on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Unfortunately I get the following error message.

```
% sudo apt-get build-dep php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-dev : Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for php5 could not be satisfied.
```

After by using the problem resolver, I can see that apt-get is trying to find a way around having the mariadb packages installed instead of the mysql packages.

```
% sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes build-dep php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 5
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 5
Investigating (0) mariadb-client-5.5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.44-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 > ( universe/database )
Broken mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-client-core-5.5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 > ( database )
  Considering mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64 -2 as a solution to mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 0
  Added mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 for mysql-client-core-5.5 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
Broken mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 Breaks on mysql-client [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 > ( database )
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 for mysql-client but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 for mysql-client but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Considering mysql-client-5.5:amd64 -3 as a solution to mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 0
  Added mysql-client-5.5:amd64 to the remove list
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 for mysql-client-5.5 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
```

This goes on for 100+ lines, full text here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11954323/

How can I build dependencies for PHP5 on Ubuntu 14.04 while using mariadb?

Comment: I installed 15.04 on a VM to see if it would work there. While it does not work, 15.04 does handle it more gracefully by suggesting to remove mariadb.

Answer (score 0):

PHP packages should compile with Maria-DB just fine. Just pick the build-dep packages by hand from `debian/control` instead of using `apt-get build-dep php5`, then change the `Build-Depends` `libmysqlclient-dev` to correct development package from Maria-DB.